# Client doesn't disconnect if connected through a proxy

Tags: c++, sockets, proxy

Note: I am mixing some C & C++ but it shouldn't be too confusing.

Connected clients are added to a multimap (might aswel have been a map, I know ^^).

**The multimap**

```
typedef std::multimap<std::string, SOCKET> clientMap;
typedef std::pair<clientMap::iterator,
                    clientMap::iterator>
                                    clientIters;
clientMap clientmap;
clientIters clientByID(std::string clientID)
{
    return clientmap.equal_range(clientID);
}
```

**Adding a client (each client runs in it's own thread)**

```
//Add clientID to map of clients
if(clientAdded == false)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << lpParam; //Use socket# as the unique ID
    clientID = ss.str();
    clientmap.insert(std::pair<std::string,SOCKET>(clientID,sock));
    clientAdded = true;
}
//Client wasn't added correctly!
if(clientID == "" || clientAdded == false)
{
    std::cout << "Problem adding client" << std::endl;
}
```

Server waits for client messages with a blocking recv() call

```
ret = recv(sock, szBuff, DEFAULT_BUFFER, 0);
if (ret == 0)        // Graceful close
    break;
else if (ret == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("recv() failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    removeUser(clientID);
    break;
}
```

**removeUser() function**

```
void removeUser(std::string clientID)
{
    std::cout << "Going to try and remove client: " << clientID << std::endl;

    //Remove client
    clientIters iters = clientByID(clientID);
    clientMap::iterator it = iters.first;
    while(it != iters.second)
    {
        clientmap.erase(it++);
        std::cout << "removed client: " << it->first << std::endl;
    }

    //Show remaining clients
    std::cout << "clients left:" << std::endl;
    for (clientMap::iterator it = clientmap.begin(); it != clientmap.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it->first << std::endl;
    }
}
```

All of this is working fine if I close a client that was connected to either my local IP or external IP (directly).

```
recv() failed: 10054
Going to try and remove client 0000008C
removed client 0000008C
clients left:
00000084
00000088
```

But if I put a proxy inbetween (using proxifier), the server thinks the connection is still active or something because the server doesn't do *anything* when I close the client. It just sits there.. waiting for nothing.

I'm using [this socket class](http://www.mycplus.com/source-code/c-source-code/tcp-client-and-server/) as a base but it's pretty heavily modified by now.

How can I make sure a closed client is definitely removed from the multimap?

Comment: My guess is the proxy software may still be keeping the connection open to your server?

Comment: @Luke according to Proxifier, the connection has been closed.

Comment: Does your call to `recv()` block indefinitely?

Comment: There is no time-out, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you store some state for each connection? like the last time something was received?

You could then periodically loop through your active connections and prune any that haven't sent anything for a long time, as the connection is more then likely stale.

Comment: Would this be safe? I use the multimap to broadcast messages to all connected clients at once, isn't it dangerous if it tries to send a message to a client that is not really connected? What would happen?

Comment: I honestly don't know, you'd have to try it and see. I'd guess sending a message to a client that's not really there shouldn't be a problem...